# Find DataTemplate key from a generic type

Tags: c#, wpf, reflection

I have the following code where I want to make it generic. So for example rather than doing NotificationView vw = new NotificationView(); in my code if the type passed in is of type NotificationView then I want to find a resource from that Type something like type.TryFindResource("")....
Is there a way to do it. Please help.

```
public static DataTemplate getDataTemplate(Type type)
        {

            NotificationView vw = new NotificationView();

            var DataTemplate = vw.TryFindResource("CustomNotificationTemplate") as DataTemplate;
            return DataTemplate;
        }
```

Comment: I don't think the tag `generics` belongs there, or are you really using *generic types* (there aren't any in your code)?

Comment: Also, i don't think you should need to construct a view to look up a `DataTemplate`, it probably should be stored in a standalone `ResourceDictionary` then, or be accessible via the `Application.Resources`.

Comment: I need a view because I am creating the view and further sending it to a NotificationService which is a devexpress Api.

Answer (score 0):

The parser implicitly creates a [`DataTemplateKey`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatemplatekey(v=vs.110).aspx) and stores the template using said key. You can construct your own, just pass the type into the constructor.

Comment: Hi i tried using DataTemplate dataTemplate = getDataTemplate(type);
and the break point dosent execute the next line it goes to an infinite loop. Please help.

Comment: How am i supposed to know where the error is if i don't know what the implementation of `getDataTemplate` is? Also, you can step into the method and see for yourself what happens.